# selecting text of textbox on focus

Tags: jquery

Hi 
I have added some format on textbox like $0.00 now what i wants is to remove the format on focus and then select the value of text box
code is :

```
$("#controlId").focus(function(){
   $(this).val(this.val().replace(/\$/g, ''));
   $(this).select();
});
```

this is working fine in IE and firefox but not in Google Chrome.

Can some body suggest me what should i do for this?

Answer (score 1):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a jQuery function, so it should look like this:

```
$("#controlId").focus(function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\$/g, ''));
   $(this).select();
});
```

Or a bit more concise/chained:

```
$("#controlId").focus(function(){
   $(this).val(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/\$/g, ''); }).select();
});
```

Comment: This is working fine on IE and firefox but problem is on google Chrome browser

Comment: @munish - can you be more specific on which part isn't working?